# Change condition in LINQ by another condition

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements

I have these two LINQ lines which are only different in one condition.

`node.Image.Tag == null` and `node.Image.Tag != null`

```
if (treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag == null) 
  {
    radNode = tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 && node.Image.Tag == null 
                           && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text));
  }
else 
  {
    radNode = tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 && node.Image.Tag != null 
                           && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text));
  }
```

Is there any way to create the condition before the LINQ line and then use it, so that I can remove the extra line?

I know I can do something like this:

```
radNode = treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag == null ? tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 
            && node.Image.Tag == null && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text)) : 
                tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 && node.Image.Tag != null 
                        && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text));
```

But it's just not what I want.

Comment: Can you write: `radNode = tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 && node.Image.Tag == treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag
                               && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text));` ? I'm asking because I'm not sure about your code logic, whether `node.Image.Tag == treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag` is correct

Comment: @KhanhTO No. it can't compare two object contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for the the outcome of condition `node.Image.Tag == null` being the same as the outcome of `treeSelected.Image.Tag == null`:

```
radNode = tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 && ((node.Image.Tag == null) == (treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag == null)) 
    && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text))
```

**Update**

Addressing @KhanTo's performance concern, in part:

```
Boolean selectedImgTagIsNull  = treeSelected.Image.Tag == null;
radNode = tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0 && ((node.Image.Tag == null) == selectedImgTagIsNull)
    && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text))
```

However, I suspect that JIT optimization would have a high likelihood of resulting in the same thing even for my original code.

Comment: This could slow down performance because of more checks for every item

Comment: @KhanhTO the check is considered as const-time operation. I'am sure that performance will be not even noticeable.

Comment: I tend to agree with @pwas, but I did make an update to show caching the treeSelected.Image.Tag == null check.   However, I think that would get optimized in my original solution, too.

Comment: So it's a good solution in my case. But I hoped there would be a better solution to match every circumstances we are facing to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that oneliner will be ok for you?

```
radNode = tree.Find(node => node.Level == 0
                    && ((treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag == nulL 
                            && node.Image.Tag == null)
                        || (treeSelectedNode.Image.Tag != nulL 
                            && node.Image.Tag != null))
                    && node.Text.Equals(treeSelectedNode.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can build that kind of query using Expression, it need extra works, here is a simple example:

```
 private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndCombined<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp2)
    {
        ParameterExpression p = exp1.Parameters.Single();
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.And(exp1.Body, Expression.Invoke(exp2, p)), exp1.Parameters.Single());
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = new List<int>() { 30, 15, 5 };

        Expression<Func<int, bool>> test1 = f => f > 10;
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> test2 = f => f < 20;
        var combinedAndQuery = AndCombined(test1, test2);

        var reuslt1 = b.Find(new Predicate<int>(combinedAndQuery.Compile()));
        Expression<Func<int, bool>> test3 = f => f < 40;


        var combinedAndQuery2 = AndCombined(test1, test3);

        var reuslt2 = b.Find(new Predicate<int>(combinedAndQuery2.Compile()));
```

}